# Spring LdapTemplate get SID from a group member

Tags: spring-ldap

In one place I run a query that gives me a certain group.

```
LdapQuery groupQuery = LdapQueryBuilder.query().where("objectCategory").is("group").and("CN").is(groupCn);
List<String> userSids = groupLdapTemplate.search(groupQuery, mapper);
```

In the mapper I have:

```
public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {
        NamingEnumeration enumeration = attrs.get("member").getAll();
        (...)
```

The problem is that I have following list of members:

```
CN=S-1-5-21-1957455145-3106008588-2947984729-1106,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=mylab2,DC=local  
CN=S-1-5-21-1957455145-3106008588-2947984729-1105,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=mylab2,DC=local
```

I want to get just their `SID`s without the rest. I am not sure how could I do that as it should be universal for different scenarios (thus variable `dn`).

I would like to avoid ugly things like below:

```
public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        NamingEnumeration enumeration = attrs.get("member").getAll();

        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String value = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
            final String sidCn = value.split(",")[0];
            result.add(sidCn.substring(3, sidCn.length()));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `ContextMapper` to manage the multiple attribute values and `LdapUtils` for parsing distinguished names:

```
ContextMapper<List<String>> mapper = new AbstractContextMapper<>() {
  public List<String> doMapFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx) {
    return Stream.of(ctx.getStringAttributes("member"))
                 .map(LdapUtils::newLdapName)
                 .map(name -> LdapUtils.getStringValue(name, name.size() - 1))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
 };

 LdapQuery groupQuery = LdapQueryBuilder.query()
                          .where("objectCategory").is("group")
                          .and("CN").is(groupCn);
 List<String> userSids = groupLdapTemplate.search(groupQuery, mapper)
                          .stream()
                          .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: why is `groupLdapTemplate.search(groupQuery, mapper);` returning a list (ArrayList with SIDs) in a list(LinkedList).

Comment: Ah, right. Slight bug in my code. Since you are doing a search, the framework expects that more than one entry might match the search criteria, so the result will be a list of the type that the ContextMapper returns. I have modified the code so that all of the returned lists of strings are mapped into a single one.